# webview play again btn

Tags: java, video, replay

I'm using here imageView , when i click on it should show me a video in (linear10) this video is about 4 sec , i need a code that when i click again on the imageView the video should start playing again , every time i clicked on the imageView i need it to start the video from the beginning

this is the code im using to play the video:

```
imageview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                n++;
                linear1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (n == 1) {
                    final VideoView vd = new VideoView(MainActivity.this); vd.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); linear1.addView(vd);
                    vd.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.mercury));
                    vd.requestFocus();
                    vd.start();
```

i tried to add this code , but this will loop the video !!! :

```
vd.setOnCompletionListener(new android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onCompletion(android.media.MediaPlayer arg0) {
                            vd.start();
                              }
                    });
```

i want when i clicked on the imageview the video starts playing, then if i clicked again it will start again from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution guys , ty for help 
someone called jeff has solve it for me  (thanks jeff)

the soulution :

put this code under onCreate:

```
vd = new VideoView(MainActivity.this); vd.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); linear1.addView(vd);
vd.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.mercury));
}
private VideoView vd;
public void nothing() {
```

and this code under imageview1 :

```
vd.requestFocus();
vd.start();
vd.seekTo(0);
```